# Posts with general ideas/discussion rather than a specific question

Tags: discussion

The actual question here is pretty specific, of course. Is it OK to post a question that is more of a general discussion question? No specifically, singly answerable question, but discussion about a topic. Or is this considered forbidden? (And if it is, I guess, does anyone have other suggestions? Reddit?)

Comment: Thanks for asking here before posting.  From the top line of the site tour: "We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:  Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such questions are not on topic on Math SE.  Some relevant guidelines can be found in the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Comment: Hrm. What if my motivation for asking is "I have found weird/surprising/extremely specific coincidence ____ that I can't explain, but takes a lot of background to describe the thing that can't be explained?"

Comment: (The Help Center link seems to imply that my question as described by my comment would be fair game.)

Comment: In that case, you are not trying to start a discussion.  You are looking for an explanation of a specific phenomenon.  Such a question is generally fine, as there is an objectively correct answer (i.e., an explanation of the phenomenon).